# Debugging without using source file in LLVM

Tags: debugging, clang, llvm, shared-libraries, llvm-clang

LLVM debugger (`lldb`) uses a source file for debugging (e.g. for breakpoint). I want to use `lldb` without having source files, only with intermediate representation files (`.ll` files).

Is it possible? If not, can I do that with `gdb` debugger? Is there another idea?

Comment: This should probably be migrated to SO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can debug using the IR, but in the worst case, you can always just debug the bare assembly without symbols of any kind. Having at least function labels is nice, though.

Comment: For there to be debugging info in the IR, it needs to be explicitly added as metadata. There's nothing implicit in IR…